# Remote MySQL ODBC connection: "Can't get hostname for your address"

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, remote-access

I run a LAMP stack on an AWS micro instance from an ISP connection that uses dynamic IPs. When my IP changes, I have to change the AWS-permitted IP to match, a nuisance, but a small one. That gives me WINscp and phpMyAdmin access. I can then change the host in the MySQL user table to the new IP to allow ODBC access.

The most recent change went fine until I came to ODBC. The MySQL Connector connects but throws  "Can't get hostname for your address".

I can't use the  '--skip-name-resolve' workaround in my.conf because of AWS security policy. It doesn't seem to be a firewall issue on the local machine - no settings changed at the IP switch. NSlookup works on the new IP.

Winscp and phpMyAdmin can obviously get the hostname. So why can't MySQL?

Comment: phpmyadmin is either hosted on the same server as MySQL server or within the same local network, so that does not count. However, DBAs or sysadmins would be in a lot better position to answer this question, rather than sw developers.

Comment: What exactly "AWS security policy" is preventing you from using '--skip-name-resolve' ?

Comment: I assume you are using RDS MySQL. If you are restricting by IP address at the RDS Security Group already, why restrict by IP address in the database as well? I would open up the database to all IPs and use the Security Group as the firewall. Of course moving your entire LAMP stack to AWS would remove these issues.

Comment: Thank you Dusan. Your comment made me look more closely at my.cnf and AWS security. skip-name-resolve now working.